# Discord.py How can I make a 4 by 4 matrix with buttons but I need those buttons to have interaction

Tags: python, discord.py

My buttons look like this and it only edits with the number that I press only one and what I want is that it edits and puts the numbers in a row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKdPT.jpg)

My goal is that when you press the buttons it will edit the top emblem with the value of buttons I am pressing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd9wZ.jpg)

My class so far looks like this code:

```
class Yamila(discord.ui.View):
     def __init__(self):
                   super().__init__()
                   self.value= None
     @discord.ui.button(label='1',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,row=0)
     async def uno(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="1",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
     @discord.ui.button(label='2',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def dos(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="2",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
         
     @discord.ui.button(label='3',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def tres(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="3",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
     @discord.ui.button(label='4',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,row=1)
     async def cuatro(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="4",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
     @discord.ui.button(label='5',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def cinco(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="5",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
         
     @discord.ui.button(label='6',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def seis(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="6",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
         
     @discord.ui.button(label='7',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,row=2)
     async def siete(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="7",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
         
     @discord.ui.button(label='8',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def ocho(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="8",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
         
         
     @discord.ui.button(label='9',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def nueve(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         embed=discord.Embed(description="9",color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
         await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you assign all buttons a row number in your decorator, otherwise, it will be automatically arranged. For example, for your 1,2,3 buttons, you will need to make sure all of their `row = 0`, etc. 
Second, if you would like to remember the number that you pressed, you can use your `self.value : str = ""` to remember it. In your button of `cinco`,

```py
self.value += "5"
embed=discord.Embed(description=self.value,color=interaction.user.color or discord.Color.random())
```

Comment: I thank you very much I finally have a matrix now my problem is this.....

```self.value += "5"
AttributeError: 'Yamila' object has no attribute 'value'.```

Comment: I removed the self.value =None above but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @silvio did you add `self.value : str = ""` in your `__init__` method?

Comment: You're right I was missing. Thank you  happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The `@discord.ui.button` decorator is useful when you want to add specific buttons. However, as you need to create an table of buttons, and they are similar, I suggest you use the `View.add_item()` method to add your buttons programmatically.
In this way, you can create a class that inherits `discord.ui.Button` to represent each squares of your table, worrying about defining only the value of the number.
See an efficient way to develop your tool:

```py
import discord


class Number(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, value: int, row: int):
        super().__init__(label=str(value), row=row, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        #   the view attribute of a button allows you to access the view in which it was added
        await self.view.add_value(interaction, self.label)


class Yamila(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ""
        super().__init__(timeout=120)
        for i in range(9):
            #   placing buttons for numbers from 1 to 9 in a 3 x 3 table
            value = i + 1
            row = i // 3
            self.add_item(Number(value, row))

    async def add_value(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, number: str):
        #   when any Number button is pressed this method will be called
        #   i'm just editing the message content. You can choose to display with Embeds too
        self.value += number
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=self.value)
```

Comment: Hello hazzu, thank you very much for your code I have modified it to look like the second image of the target I want to reach and when I press buttons that do not contain numbers but emojis I get an error. In such a case how to detect that I am pressing a button that contains an emoji. I would need a label or a custom_id. Your code has given me a terrible dizziness but it is written in few lines of code I am surprised.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `Number` button class I developed is meant to represent number buttons. You need to create new classes of `Delete` and `Enter` buttons with their callbacks defined to execute the desired functions